# Is there an updates log in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administration

I am diagnosing a botched upgrade in a Joomla component. In order to find out exactly what happened, it would be really helpful to have a log of all the updates (system, extensions, components...) performed on the system: on this day this plugin was updated, on this day that other component was updated...

Is there such a log? (Joomla 3.6).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such activity log feature in the Joomla core but you could install a third party extension such as the [LOGman](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/administration/admin-reports/logman/) paid extension or similar.

According to the documentation, [logged activities](https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/logman/documentation/getting-started/#what-actions-are-logged) include installs, upgrades and uninstalls using the Joomla Installer.

Of course, this probably won't help you in this instance because LOGman only logs activity after it has been installed.

**November 2018 Update:**

With the release of Joomla 3.9.0, a user action log is now included in the Joomla core. Actions such as log in, log out, extension updates, article updates and extension configuration changes can be logged. Remember to enable the action log plugins for this to work.

Comment: I'd also include the following as info: It's not a log, but for what the OP is asking (and I was googling for as well), one useful indicator is the filesystem modified date for files. You can deduce when the *last* update took place, if it was a system upgrade, an extension upgrade and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No - Joomla doesn't store the history of updates anywhere, but this is a good idea to have.

If you're diagnosing a botched update, then the first thing that you need to do is to find out what the error is (by setting the error_reporting to "maximum" in your configuration.php file). If that doesn't work, then try disabling plugins one by one (last ones installed first).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me explain in more detail: the site is still up and running. The only problem is that I noticed some oddities in a component, and after examining it, found out that its code was a mix between the latest version and a previous one. I talked to a junior admin, who says that "he thinks" he updated it through Joomla's control panel... and when I go to the component's webpage, it has a warning that says: "no, you can't install this update though Joomla's CP! You need to use our own installer!" All of this happened a month ago.

Comment: So, to summarize, the steps you suggest are of no use in this case, because the site still works (more or less). I'm just trying to find out exactly what happened, which version was upgraded to which version.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the old website? If yes, then you can compare both versions. By the way, you can always uninstall a component and then re-install it, and then copy the data afterwards. This might solve your problem.